# How to NOT count the characters in lines that start with '#' in a text file with python

Tags: python

I have this code that reads lines in a text file and counts the characters and stops once it reaches 1000 characters or more. How can I modify it so it doesn't count characters on any line that begins with a # sign?

```
infile = open('word_count.tst', 'r') #word_count is just a sample file.
lines = infile.readlines()
char_count = 0
for line in lines:
    char_count = char_count + len(line)
    if char_count >= 1000:
        break
print("File has %d characters" % (char_count))
```

Comment: add a hook checking if `line.startswith('#')`

Answer (score 1):

Open file with `with` statement. Don't read all the lines just iterate over the file object. Use short hand for `a = a + b` as `a += b`. Check if line starts with `#` with `string.startswith()` function and negate it with `not` to get the desired condition.

You can do it like so:

```
char_count = 0
with open('word_count.tst', 'r') as f:
    for l in f:
        if not l.startswith('#'):
            char_count += len(l)
            if char_count >= 1000:
                break
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `if line[0] != "#":` to the code:

```
f = open('word_count.txt', 'r') #word_count is just a sample file.
char_count = 0
for line in f:
    if line[0] != "#":
        char_count = char_count + len(line)
        if char_count >= 1000:
            break
print("File has %d characters" % (char_count))
```